# Why does Veracode still report CWE-89 after my function has been parameterized?

Tags: security, sql-injection, veracode

According to recommendation of CWE-89, my function below has been parameterized, but Veracode still reports that CWE-89 is available in that function.

As you can see that the function is used for generating dynamic SQL queries base on input parameters. And, there is **only** @PrimaryValue parameter **came from user input** while **other dynamic variables** behind SELECT, FROM, JOIN, ON and WHERE **are queried from database** (not from user input).

How do you think about this case? Can I propose a mitigation for this it or I have to modify the code more to solve the problem? Please advice for me.

[image]

Comment: I understand you said the variables you are concatenating into your query come from a config database, but how can Veracode know that? All it sees is code variables being concatenated into an SQL query. It can make no assumption that the values are valid SQL identifiers. SQL injection is not only from user input, it can be any content. SQL injection is also not always malicious, it could be a simple mistake. Such accidents are more likely to result in an invalid SQL query, instead of a data breach, but it's still counts as SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has SQL injection problem. For example user can pass to this method, param "intofile" like this:

```
* FROM Table1; DROP TABLE table2; intofile
```

With this code user convert your query to 3 queries and after run it table2 is drop.

First of all you have to run your query in a read only transaction. After that you have to use a SQL escape method over all inputs to delete key words like DROP from it.

Comment: Yes, I knew that problem with intofile variable. But, as I said, all variables behind SELECT, FROM, JOIN, ON and WHERE are queried from database, not from user input. There is only @PrimaryValue parameter came from user input. So, in this case, your concern cannot happen.

Comment: @RDeveloper - when you say that they're queried from the database, that *may or may not* be protection. It depends on whether you're saying that they were retrieved via *metadata* queries of your own design or whether they're coming from normal columns in normal tables, in which case you still have an injection risk, it's just a *stored* injection risk. In either case though, the analysis tool is probably not capable of *reasoning* about how you obtained these values, all it knows is that you're mashing *data* and *code* together into a string in such a way that there's a risk of misinterpret

Comment: it depend on your project,this method has sql injection in some of inputs but if you say all input except @PrimaryValue is checked out of this method so the method that call this maybe is safe, It seems to be safe

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The SQL query in my application is generated dynamically based on configuration stored in the database. And, only administrators can add/update that configuration. And one more thing, before administrator adds/updates that configuration, it has been validated to prevent SQL injection. So, yes, they are protection already except the PrimaryValue parameter in the function above.

Comment: its a good idea to validate those parameters before saved in database by admin but i prefer to validate the parameters in this method, because Maybe those parameters changed in data base by some code or some person and its a risk of your design but if you  validate the parameters in this method you can handle the risk